# Assembly How to translate opcode DIV to C Code

Tags: c, assembly, x86, machine-code, code-translation

Hey I know I been asking alot of questions.. but not much resources on this on google so hopefully this will help future people who attempt to do similar projects, I always google solutions as well, but I never search passed first page.

I looked at that Intel manual Alex posted, seems pretty alien to me
http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2a-2b-instruction-set-a-z-manual.html

So I thought I knew how a simple `DIV` opcode worked. Since it's just `divide` after all.
I had no difficulty adding `ADD`,`SUB`, of course `IMUL` had problems you guys helped me out on that one. Seems `DIV` falls into the same category as `IMUL` in terms of difficulty.

Well without using the manual just doing self debugging tests with OllyDbg.

I found out answer of division is always stored in `EAX`. Figured out the remainder is also kept who knew, stored in `EDX`.

Which from studying this algorithm is extremely important who knew, someone would use the remainder of a random number division to generate a switch from 0-10 pretty clever.. But still my question.

It's already strange I never thought of hexadecimal numbers of being divided would have remainders decimal points don't even belong in them.

```
DIV ECX
```

would be like

```
regs.d.eax /= regs.d.ecx;
regs.d.edx = regs.d.eax % regs.d.ecx;
```

I was thinking maybe getting remainder first.. will simply things.

```
regs.d.edx = regs.d.eax % regs.d.ecx;
regs.d.eax /= regs.d.ecx;
```

Okay I hardly work with mathematical programming so it's a bit confusing for me. I'm more of a guy that would store the result in a string then split it by decimal point and that's how I would get the remainder yeah I know it's slow and it's taking the easy path out.. and I myself am against using string operations in a mathematical code.

Ok well.. looking at that C code I put there.. probably have to store both `EAX` and `ECX` before division happens in temporary variables.. or do the remainder code first.. then division code second. I don't know.

Well I'll see maybe you guys can provide me with a better answer perhaps it cannot be done in one line but maybe I made a few mistakes.. I can't really test the things I do right now due to many other things I have to fix before I can even compile the software.

Comment: I wonder if your ADD/ADC/SUB/SBB set flags properly (SF, CF, OF, AF, PF; ZF is trivial, though).

Comment: I don't even have flags. I'm trying to avoid them for now. I said I only have registers and I look out for stack which is a byte array of 65k elements. Assembly is filled with things just to confuse me.. but I tend to avoid those things hehe. Like `cHao` told me `RET 0/RET` just returns the return address of a function so it knows where to go back I guess.. do I really need that in my case? my functions will return how C/C++ functions work anyways so it's useless, Probably same with flags I'll see if I run into problems not using flags for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manuals are no easy reading, true, but they have all the answers to your questions (well, most of them, there are occasional omissions and mistakes in the docs).

One thing you're missing in your guessed algorithm is that DIV typically divides 2N bits by N bits, that is, when you do `DIV ECX` you divide a 64-bit unsigned value contained in EDX:EAX by a 32-bit unsigned value in ECX. The quotient is then stored in EAX and the remainder in EDX.

You should also remember about the possibility of a division overflow (in this case EDX>=ECX is the condition for it) and flags that the instruction modifies in the EFLAGS register.

Comment: Well tell me what I have to use other then modulus (%) to get a remainder that's always the same as in assembly. I'll setup a test one to brute force get all 8 billion divisions and log all remainders of real assembly and then same test on emulator to see if anything is wrong later.

Comment: If your E*X members are unsigned, you can use / and % to get unsigned division just as with DIV. But you still need to do 64-bit division here. Do this: `unsigned long long dividend = (unsigned long long)...EDX + ...EAX;` then `...EAX = (whatever is 32-bit unsigned type)(dividend / ...ECX);` `...EDX = (whatever is 32-bit unsigned type)(dividend % ...ECX);`.

Comment: So this is all of it `unsigned long dividend = (unsigned long) regs.d.edx + regs.d.eax;`
`regs.d.eax = (signed int) (dividend / regs.d.ecx);`
`regs.d.edx = (signed int) (dividend % regs.d.ecx);` I use Visual Studio so long should be 64 bits. But.. registers eax,edx all unsigned.. and I pass signed to them. A bit confusing.. but i'll leave it, I guess.

Comment: @SSpoke: **long = 32 bits** in Visual Studio. Don't drop the 2nd long (`long long` is at least 64 bit long in C, whereas `long` is at least 32) or use `__int64` in place of `long long` since you're using MSVC++. I had a typo, `signed` is wrong, it must be `unsigned` everywhere for DIV. See the updated comment.

Comment: haha dam even MSVC++ is confusing.. i always thought this pattern..  `(byte/char 8)` `(short 16)` `(int 32)` `(long 64)` `(long long 128)` LOL.. really strange why  `(int/long)` mean same thing all of a sudden.. yeah I'll make everything unsigned thank you for your time

Comment: @SSpoke: read the C(++) standard and the documentation for your compiler to know thy types and other 'strange' things. :) What am I saying... Who's reading these days... :)

Comment: Nicely said, my reading is very hard for me, hard to keep both attention to subjects and to understand what I am reading in very basic terms. If I read something.. that sounds okay I keep reading never understood what that was.. to me.. was just guess work, same as I am doing now :D. Hopefully I will be done with programming altogether soon and become mechanical engineer. No reading required to screw in a wheel hahahaha.

Answer (score 0):

I think a reasonably fair translation would be:

```
  int16_t a=42,b=7;
  int16_t div = a/7;
  int16_t remainder = a - (div*b);
```

In practice, this *may, or may not* be equivalent to `remainder = a % b` (I'd need to look up the standard specs). It gets more interesting if you consider carefully what happens with negative numbers.

All that said, the decimal point never comes into play, so I don't see why you mention it in the post.

> **perhaps it cannot be done in one line** [...]

I highly suspect the compiler will pick up on the reuse of subexpressions, and automatically use the remainder from (E)DX when applicable. (this is rather trivial optimization for a compiler)

Comment: No joke that's whats happening in this algorithm `DIV ECX`,  `MOV EDI,EDX`, `CMP EDI,4`, `JNZ SHORT XXXXXXX` it's working merely off remainders. Nevermind.. I think we both are talking about different things now. `DIV` from that Intel manual is unsigned division only... so i will not worry about negative numbers ever.

Comment: DIV performs unsigned division. int16_t is a signed type and your example therefore does signed division. Also, per the C standard, the [signed integer division using `/` and `%` is not guaranteed to round towards 0](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Integer-Division.html).